# How to change variable in dependence on GET?

Tags: php

I have a series of variables, like so:

```
$a1 = '...';
$a2 = '...';
$a3 = '...';
// maybe more ...
```

Now, I need to find the related variable using a GET parameter. As in, if `?n=2`, I need to pass `$a2` to a function:

```
$b = $_GET['n']; // ?n=2
$the_variable_selected = ?? // Here I need to get $a2

ss($the_variable_selected);

function ss ($aN) { ... }
```

How do I do this?

Comment: This is very unclear. What is the intended output of `ss()`? Are you trying to compare the values of `$a1` and `$aN`?

Comment: @Jared Farrish, no, a1, a2, a3 - arrays. and I want to choose one of them depending on the _GET data.

Comment: How is anyone supposed to understand `$a1` is some kind of array? Please clarify you question.

Comment: @Jared Farrish, What's the difference? I just wish to address to necessary variables selected.

Comment: If you're asking how to get a variable using a variable, see [the PHP manual](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) and Geseft's answer.

Comment: Writing clear questions on SO can be challenging; in fact, it's part of the reason SO was created (to teach programmers how to write better). I've re-written the question to demonstrate how it could be more clearly expressed, as a demonstration. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $a1 = aaa;
//   $a2 = bbb;
//   $a3 = ccc;
 $aN = xxxx;
 $b = "a".$_GET["aN"];
 ss($$b);
 function ss($var){
    //do with the variable what you want

 }
```

Explanation of the code: 
In the $b variable you are building up your variable name ( it will be a1 or aN depending on the _GET ).

$$b is a variable of variable :). It looks like this: $($b), witch if we take the value of $b, will be $(a1) = $a1 or $(aN) = $aN.

(I did not get correctly if N is referring to a number or its actually a character, if the latter here is another version ):

```
$a1 = aaa;
 $aN = xxxx;
 $b;
 if($_GET["aN"] == "N")
    $b = $aN;
 else
   $b = $a1;
 ss($b);
 function ss($var){
        //do with the variable what you want

     }
```

Comment: If this is indeed what the OP is after, the man page is here: http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.variables.variable.php